# confused about delegate pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard, subclass

I'm creating a custom UIView subclass (**shareView**) from a Nib. 
I created a custom protocol for **shareView** like this:

```
@protocol sharePopupDelegate
@required

-(void)userPublishedContent;
-(void)userAbortedPublish;

@end

@interface shareView : UIView
{
     id<sharePopupDelegate> delegate;
}
```

In my main.storyboard I created a custom UIViewController **myViewController** with a **shareView** view instance called "**popup**" inside.

So now I got

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet shareView *popup;
```

I would like now to delegate **myViewController** from **shareView** methods i declared, so I did

```
self.popup.delegate = self;
```

inside myViewController but the protocols' methods are not being called inside myViewController.

So i correctly see the **shareView** instance but cannot interface to its delegate.

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First off, dont do this id<sharePopupDelegate> delegate;  Make it a weak property.  Please post the code for when shareView Performs the delegate methods on its delegate.  I am looking for something like this: [self.delegate userPublishedContent];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the protocol declared in myViewController.

For example

```
   @interface MyViewController : UIViewCOntroller <sharePopupDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this section of the code:

```
@interface shareView : UIView
{
     id<sharePopupDelegate> delegate;
}
```

You are creating a strong reference to the delegate, which is not what you want most of the time.  Change it to this:

```
@interface shareView : UIView
@property(weak, nonatomic) id<sharePopupDelegate> delegate;
```

The shareView class itself must have some way to know when a user publishes content.  Maybe you have an action linked up to the shareView which calls a method in the shareView class.  For examaple:

```
- (void)publishButtonTapped {
// some code
}
```

What you want to do is let the delegate know in that method, something like this:

```
- (void)publishButtonTapped {

// some code
[self.delegate userPublishedContent];
}
```

Then whatever action the user takes to cancel:

```
- (void)cancelButtonTapped {

// some code
[self.delegate userAbortedPublish];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but unfortunatelly didn't solve, I think the problem is about the line: "self.popup.delegate = self". A kind of self assign of delegate protocol that should be forbidden, but no idea of how to solve

Comment: I don't think that part is the problem, show the code for the .m of shareView.  If you dont have [self.delegate userPublishedContent], thats probably the problem.  If you do, set a breakpoint and see if it ever gets hit.